# Java8 convert csv to json object

Tags: java, spring, csv, csvtojson

i am comparing two json objects, one of them get request and other input from csv file ---
for the csv to json logic -- following code,

csv file looks like this ----
the csv file looks like this -

```
sw product,sw product module,technology
Product 1,Module 1,REGULAR
Product 1,Module 2,SPRING CLOUD
Product 2,Module 1,REGULAR
Product 2,Module 3,REGULAR
```

JAVA CODE

```
package com.beandependencyinjection.configurationbeans.service;

public class ConvertCsvToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String filesss = "C:\products\\swproduct.csv";
        ConvertCsvToJson result = new ConvertCsvToJson();

        System.out.println(result.CSVtoJSON(filesss));


    }

    public String CSVtoJSON(String output) {

            String[] lines = output.split(",");

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append('[');
            String[] headers = new String[0];

            //CSV TO JSON
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                String[] values = lines[i].replaceAll(",", "").split("۞");

                if (i == 0) //INDEX LIST
                {
                    headers = values;
                } else {
                    builder.append('{');
                    for (int j = 0; j < values.length && j < headers.length; j++) {

                        String jsonvalue = "\"" + headers[j] + "\":\"" + values[j] + "\"";
                        if (j != values.length - 1) { //if not last value of values...
                            jsonvalue += ',';
                        }
                        builder.append(jsonvalue);
                    }
                    builder.append('}');
                    if (i != lines.length - 1) {
                        builder.append(',');
                    }
                }
            }
            builder.append(']');
            output = builder.toString();

            return output;
        }
}
```

but its not working -- any help appreciated

Comment: What error do you get, if not error what output do you get?

Comment: output is [] only

Comment: what is the purpose of `split("۞")`?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks very low level.
Instead, you can do it like this and make use of the `ObjectMapper` class.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
    List < Product > products = in .lines().skip(1).map(line - > {
        String[] fields = pattern.split(line);
        return new Product(...use values in fields to create product...);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.writeValue(System.out, products);
}
```

More details are available [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-java)

Comment: Just an FYI, The pattern that you are using will not work in case there is a ',' available as part of Column String, for eg Column value "abc, xyz"

Comment: Point taken, but this does not seem to be the case given the example data in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your own logic to parse CSV and convert it to JSON, you can take use of some libraries.

For Reading CSV you can use opencsv, this gives you option to directly read a CSV to a Map

```
Map<String, String> values = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(new FileReader("yourfile.csv")).readMap();
```

Post this you can use Jackon to convert map to a JSON.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

There are many different frameworks available for Reading CSV file and converting text to JSON, you can explore.